# css vertical line between two elements

Tags: html, css

I have two elements one section element and one aside element, the aside element is always the same through all my under pages, In each section I have different length of content depending on the page but my problem is that between the section and the aside I want a gray vertical line in the middle space between them.

It would be appreciated to not get any solution including Java Script.

So any suggestions?

Edit:

thanks for the response so far but my problem is that I want the line to be the height of the one that is longest for example on my start page the longest one is the content but for another under page the longest one is the aside and the aside is inside another php document that I link together because that will always be the same content on the pages until I change it, sorry that this info is late!

Comment: Please post the relevant code and/or provide an online example

Answer (score 1):

How about a `border-left: 1px solid #000;` for the right element?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<div class="line" >
Second element
</div>
```

In css :

```
.line {
    border-left: thick solid #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: FYI: `<div>` is a container tag and the `</div>` closing tag [cannot be omitted](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the line the height of the aside (which I will assume is on the left) then a border right on the aside will work:

```
.aside{
    border-right: 1px solid #666;
}
```

If the line should be the height of the content, then a border left on the content should do:

```
.content{
    border-left: 1px solid #666;
}
```

If the elements are the other way round then simply reverse the border used.

You may then need to add some padding in so that text is not touching the border depending on the rest of your styling and mark-up.